# How do I extract a diagonal into a column vector?

Tags: matrix, octave

Assume matrix `M`:

```
1 2 3
3 5 6
6 8 9
```

How do I store I extract the following row vector `a` from it?

```
1
5
9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use [diag](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/diag.html):

```
octave-3.4.0:1> A = [ 1 2 3; 3 5 6; 6 8 9 ]
A =

   1   2   3
   3   5   6
   6   8   9

octave-3.4.0:2> D = diag(A)
D =

   1
   5
   9
```

Note that you can also extract other diagonals by passing a second parameter to `diag`, e.g.

```
octave-3.4.0:3> D = diag(A, 1)
D =

   2
   6

octave-3.4.0:4> D = diag(A, -1)
D =

   3
   8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimensions of your matrix (square or otherwise), you can extract any diagonal you like, or even modified diagonals (such as numbers in (1,1), (2,3), (3,5), etc), somewhat faster than using diag, by simply using an index call like this:

```
a=M(1:4:9)
```

(note: this produces a row vector; for a column vector, just transpose) For an NxN matrix, simply start at the desired value (1 for the top-left corner, 2 for next one down vertically, and so on), then increment by N+1 until you reach the appropriate value.

```
octave:35> tic; for i=1:10000 diag(rand(3)); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.13973 seconds.
octave:36> tic; for i=1:10000 rand(3)(1:4:9); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.10966 seconds.
```

For reference:

```
octave:49> tic; for i=1:10000 rand(3); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.082429 seconds.
octave:107> version
ans = 3.6.3
```

So the overhead for the for loop and the rand function, subtracted off, shows that using indices is about twice as fast as using diag. I suspect that this is purely due to the overhead of calling diag, as the operation itself is very straightforward and fast, and is almost certainly how diag itself works.